# Error building doxygen1.8.6

Tags: doxygen

Just got the latest duoxygen 1.8.6 on Linux
Currently have 1.8.5 installed. It build fine.
With 1.8.6 am gettign the following error:

```
gmake[2]: Entering directory `/home/build/doxygen/doxygen-1.8.6/src'
/usr/bin/flex -PconfigYY -t config.l >config.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -fsigned-char -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wall -W -O2 -I../qtools -o ../objects/config.o config.cpp
config.l: In member function bool Config::parse(const char*):
config.l:1692: error: configYY_flex_debug was not declared in this scope
gmake[2]: *** [../objects/config.o] Error 1
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With release 1.8.6 a newer version of flex is required to build doxygen. Try version 2.5.35 or later.

See also https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=719525